# Ease life in dependently typed programming using `Function` and `Program` in Coq

Tags: coq

I am trying to implement a dependently typed evaluator of STLC in Coq using `Program Fixpoint`. Since the language does not have fixed point operator, I think the evaluator should terminate, though the termination condition is not structural.

During my development, I find one source of headache is I simply can't keep track of too many variables at the same time, and pattern matching is too nested.

If it were about a mere `Fixpoint`, I can just implement the body using tactics, but when using `Program Fixpoint` or `Function`, I just cannot. Is there any trick to build body using tactics in this case?

I am stuck at very end: https://gist.github.com/HuStmpHrrr/0d92e646916ae9ec7ced3ff21724ba2d

Comment: Termination of STLC is very non-obvious. Your environment machine implementation needs at least some logical relations for a termination proof, [like here](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~psztxa/publ/jtait07.pdf). I imagine finding a measure for `Program` would be difficult.

Comment: @AndrásKovács yeah, you confirmed my intuition. it's not quite straightforward. I haven't done it, but I think that it needs to show evaluation of variable shrinks the context, so that the measure can be proven shrunk too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `Program`, you can simply leave underscores for parts of your term you want to fill in using proof mode. Any underscores that can be inferred will automatically be filled in and the remaining will produce obligations. For example, you can write all of `run` in proof mode by writing `Program Fixpoint run ... {measure ...} := _.` The measure will show up as an argument to `run` in the context.

Comment: what about `Function`? isn't there a way to define it using tactics as well? also, I can imagine it's going to be difficult to prove properties for program, is it not? Is there any example to show how to prove properties for `Program`? I wish there can be something like `_equation` as in `Function`.